# Getting the original video quality while converting in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

In my site, having upload video(only mp4 videos) functionality and then to combine. For the combining i used Mp4Box, If we want combine all the mp4 video, those videos have to same dimesions,bitrate,codecs,samplerate,etc, So while uploading the mp4 videos itself we set the constant dimension and other details like
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -r 25 -s 640x360 -ar 48000 -acodec copy -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -vpre default -async 1 -strict -2 -qscale 10 test.mp4

After using this command the video quality will loss fro the original video, Kindly suggest any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
-qp 0
```

[§ Lossless H.264](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide#LosslessH.264)

Comment: After adding the this, i got error as Invalid value '0' for option 'qp'

Comment: I am using -crf 23 instead od -qp 0 , now its getting the original video quality.Anyway thanks for ur kind replies

Comment: @rajeshkumar `libx264` ignores `-qscale` and will use `-crf 23` by default if no valid rate control method is provided, so I do not see how adding `-crf 23` would make a difference from your original command unless perhaps you're using an ancient build of `ffmpeg`. This is one reason why the complete console output from your command is important to include.